# Install a Chrome Extension with many permissions in a Chromium based browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, electron, chromium

I’m trying to build an electron desktop app that just includes a specific Chrome extension built-in.

The problem I have is that the extension does not load on my electron app, because the extension requires some chrome APIs that are not supported on electron (i.e cookies, webNavigation).

Is there any way to install Chrome Extensions with those permissions into an Electron or other Chromium-based browser?